# what are the fast moving white objects in JCSAT-18 separation video

Tags: identify-this-object

Fast moving objects seen at 0:27 (bottom), 0:30 (middle), 0:32 (top and bottom right) etc. What are they?
They don't seem to originate from the rocket or the payload.

Are they other satellites? I thought that space is so big and ill-lit that we are unlikely to see so many other satellites in such a short duration.

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]
[image: pic3]

Comment: How did you conclude that "They don't seem to originate from the rocket or the payload. "?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Nothing definite. The objects seem to originate from the left side of the video near what I think is the horizon / earth (bright bluish line). It also looked like they are following curved paths as well as being farther away from the camera than the satellite.

Comment: The booster is over to the left as well.

Comment: So just debris from the separation ?

Comment: On frame by frame play, It does seem to originate from the booster and the satellite.

Comment: If you have figured it out, feel free to answer your own question, that is fine on stack exchange https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17847/299013  Welcome to space!